# Does pcap_breakloop() flushes packets in the packet buffer before pcap_loop() returns?

Tags: libpcap

I have a library which uses libpcap to capture packets. I'm using `pcap_loop()` in a dedicated thread for the capture and `pcap_breakloop()` to stop the capture.
The *packet buffer timeout* is set to 500ms.

In some rare cases I am missing the last packets that my application sends before calling pcap_breakloop().

Reading the libpcap documentation I ended up wondering if the packet loss is related to the *packet buffer timeout*. The documentation says:

> packets are not delivered as soon as they arrive, but are delivered after a short delay (called a "packet buffer timeout")

What happens if `pcap_breakloop()` is called during this delay ? Are the packets in the buffer passed to the callback or are they dropped before `pcap_loop()` returns ?
I was unable to find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are the packets in the buffer passed to the callback

No.

> or are they dropped before pcap_loop() returns ?

Yes.  In capture mechanisms that buffer packets in kernel code and deliver them only when the buffer fills up or the timeout expires `pcap_breakloop()` doesn't force the packets to be delivered.

For *some* of those capture mechanisms there *might* be a way to force the timeout to, in effect, expire, but I don't know of any *documented* way to do that with Linux PF_PACKET sockets, BPF, or WinPcap/Npcap NPF.

Update, giving more details:

On Linux and Windows, `pcap_breakloop()` attempt to wake up anything that's blocked waiting for packets on the same `pcap_t`.

On Linux, this is implemented by having the `poll()` call in libpcap block on both the PF_PACKET socket being used for capturing and on an "event" descriptor; `pcap_breakloop()` causes the "event" descriptor to supply an event, so that the `poll()` wakes up even if there are no packets to pick up from the socket yet.  That does *not* force the current chunk in the buffer (memory shared between the kernel and userland code) to be assigned to userland, so they're not provided to the caller of libpcap.

On Windows, with Npcap, an "event object" is used by the driver and Packet32 library (the libpcap part of Npcap calls routines in the Packet32 library) to allow the library to block waiting for packets and the driver to wake the library up when packets are available.  `pcap_breakloop()` does a `SetEvent()` call on the handle for that object, which forces userland code waiting for packets to wake up; it then tries to read from the device.  I'd have to spend more time looking at the driver code to see whether, if there are be buffered-but-not-delivered packets at that point, they will be delivered.

On all other platforms, `pcap_breakloop()` does *not* deliver a wakeup, as the capture mechanism either does no buffering or provides no mechanism to force a wakeup, so:

- if no buffering is done, there's no packet buffer to flush;
- if there's a timeout, code blocked on a read will be woken up when the timeout expires, and that buffer will be delivered to userland;
- if there's no timeout, code blocked on a read could be blocked for an indefinite period of time.

The *ideal* situation would be if the capture mechanism provided, on all platforms that do buffering, a way for userland code to force the current buffer to be delivered, and thus to cause a wakeup.  That would require changes to the NPF driver and Packet32 library in Npcap, and would require kernel changes in Linux, *BSD, macOS, Solaris, and AIX.

Update 2:

Note also that "break loop" means *break out of the loop immediately*, so even if all of the above were done, when the loop is exited, there might be packets remaining in libpcap's userland buffer.  If you want those packets - even though, by calling `pcap_breakloop()`, you told libpcap "stop giving me packets" - you'll have put the `pcap_t` in non-blocking mode and call `pcap_dispatch()` to drain the userland buffer.  (That won't drain the kernel buffer.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any reference about this behavior ? Or a documentation I could refer to ?

Comment: "do you have any reference about this behavior ? Or a documentation I could refer to ?"  No, I haven't updated the man pages to mention this.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed updates. I am using the libcap under Linux and what I understand is that I could use pcap_dispatch() to grab packets in the userland buffer but the way PF_PACKET works packets are likely to be in kernel buffer which I have no way to flush. Is that correct ?

Comment: Sort of, but, for memory-mapped capture (which is the default in some older versions of libpcap and the *only* form of capture in newer ones), there's only one buffer, in both kernel and user address space, shared by the kernel and user, and there's no way to force the kernel to hand userland a buffer segment (and userland shouldn't look at anythingng other than the "belongs to the kernel" flag in chunks that belong to the kernel).

Comment: I've updated the man page; for the full painful story, read the pcap_breakloop() man page at https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap_breakloop.3pcap.html.

Comment: I looked at the update and added a call to pcap_dispatch() after pcap_loop() to try fetch remaining packets but it doesn't work in every situation. If packets are pending, pcap_dispatch() grabs the packets and returns, if no packets are pending pcap_dispatch() never returns which is not what I want. Setting pcap_t to non-blocking makes pcap_dispatch() return immediately with no packets (probably because packet buffer timeout is still running). I did pass a timeout of 500ms to pcap_open_live().